# How to find a sum $10\log_{10}{\frac{A}{1}} + 10\log_{10}{\frac{B}{1}}$ in not log scale.

Tags: calculus

It is kind a school question, but I don't see it. For example, we have 150 [mW] and 200 [mW], in log scale it is equal to $10\log_{10}{\frac{150}{1}} = 21.76 [dBm] $ and $10\log_{10}{\frac{200}{1}} = 23.01 [dBm]$. I need to find a sum of $150 [mW] + 200 [mW] = 350 [mW]$ but in log scale using $21.76 [dBm] + 23.01  [dBm] = 25.44 [dBm]$. It is important because mostly values from -50 [dBm] to -150 [dBm] are used, which are small values on normal scale.

Comment: Seems like you just reverse the process, no? You start with 21.76 dB and 23.01 dB, turn them into 2.176 B and 2.301 B, turn those into 150 mW and 200 mW (by exponentiating with base ten), and then adding them to get 350 mW, then taking the logarithm to get 2.544 B, then multiplying by ten to get 25.44 dB. Does that sound right? If $X=21.76$ and $Y=23.01$ then this operation is $10\log (10^{X/10}+10^{Y/10})=25.44$.

Comment: Yes it is right, but what if we will use -120 dB and -134 dB? The values will be small. And arithmetic is not good with floating point values in programming languages. Or am I wrong?

Comment: If $X<Y$ you can factor $10^{X/10}$ out of $10^{X/10}+10^{Y/10}$ to get $10^{X/10}(1+10^{(Y-X)/10})$, and then $10\log(10^{X/10}+10^{Y/10})$ becomes $X+10\log(1+10^{(Y-X)/10})$.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!